# min_max_scaler.fit_transform: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, dataframe, valueerror

I'm using min_max_scaler.fit_transform() to rescale each column in the Dataframe - df.

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df[['A', 'B', 'C']])
```

I got the ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. However, this error only occurs when I process one of my csv files. All others work fine. I don't know where should I start to debug? Can anyone suggest some directions to figure out the issue?

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    569         if y is None:
    570             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 571             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    572         else:
    573             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    337         # Reset internal state before fitting
    338         self._reset()
--> 339         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    340 
    341     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    371         X = check_array(X,
    372                         estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
--> 373                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    374 
    375         data_min = np.nanmin(X, axis=0)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    529                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    530                 else:
--> 531                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    532             except ComplexWarning:
    533                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Not quite sure about the specific error. But minmaxscaler can work with a 2darray, no need to iterate over the columns

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I updated my code. however, the error still exist.

Comment: You might want to make sure none of your df elements contain sequences (lists, sets etc.)